# How can I parse the email using Mailgun?

Tags: php, parsing, email, mailgun

by refering [this](http://hasin.me/2012/11/16/parsing-inbound-emails-with-mailgun-how-to/) article, I tried to parse the email, but i am failing to do it.

I have created free-account on mailgun, created domain, mailbox, etc.
I sent one mail from my personal email ID to say, `mgtest1@my_domain_name.mailgun.com`

I have configured the account to forward all mails to `"http://project_name/controller_name/action_name" (in case of zend)` 
OR

```
"http://localhost/project_name/file_name.php" (for plain PHP)
```

It is said that I can access the mail using `$_POST (for PHP)`, but **I am getting blank array.**

Where I am going wrong ?

I tried with both Zend and plain PHP. I am simply using print_r($_POST).

Answer (score 2):

print_r() is used for printing to the screen. Since the web hook handler is posting to your script, the handler saw the posted data, but you didn't. ;)

You should store the data by serializing the array and storing it in a file.

```
<?PHP
$data = serialize($_POST);
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

OR access the data directly:

```
<?PHP
$data = $_POST['recipient'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Hope that helps! Come chat with us, or send us a ticket, if you still have trouble.

Thanks!
Travis S
Mailgun Support

Comment: For me, its not working on localhost. Is it for live sites only?

Comment: This is what it shows in text file created (using serialize) :- "a:0:{}"

Comment: Do you have PHP error logging enabled? Try checking your logs to see if there is an issue with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun cannot POST messages to localhost. You need to migrate your project to an online server. Right now, the route you have provided is of your localhost server, there is no way for mailgun to access that.

Comment: or you can use ngrok.exe